# Finding the order in which fields of a class were declared

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

The aim is to allow the programmer to write a .NET class (or struct) containing fields (or properties) as meta-data, to be interpreted by run-time code.

So the programmer would write:

```
class foo {
  int x;
  string y;
  double z;
}
```

Then the run-time code would use this as instructions to deserialise a stream (one field at a time) and fill an instance of the class.

The actual layout of the class is unimportant, so SequentialLayoutAttribute is no help. It's the order in which the fields were declared that matters, and Reflection rather helpfully points out that members are retrieved in no particular order.

Comment: I think you're probably going to have to use attributes for this - maybe use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx (There is an order property in that annotation). Bit of a pain and not as automated as you would have hoped, but I am not sure that this is possible!

Comment: Are you trying to semi-automagically support reading existing data into instances of new classes or is this completely new code that should be using [serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)?

Comment: @adaam: You're probably right. It's surprising how often the answer to questions like this is: use attributes.

Comment: @HABO: The former. The serialisation format is non-standard (but simple), the field order is pre-determined and there could be a lot of different structures.

Comment: @adaam: if you want to turn that into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.